# dimension.xml for multiple displays

Tags: android, xml

I need to generate `textview -s` by code and specify different text sizes for different screens (xhdpi,hdpi, etc.)
I found some way using `dimension.xml` and specify different `values` folders (values-xhdpi and etc.) but only `dimension.xml` is different so I don't want to copy paste all other contents in all `values` folders.
Is it possible to write for example dimension-xhdpi.xml?

or do you have another idea to implement this?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks it works. put it as a answer I will approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy only the different dimension files in the folders.
No need to copy what remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Create the different values folders and only put the dimensions.xml file in them. You dont know to put all your resource files in each folder.

If you are willing to make a separate apk for each screen size, then its possible to do this using gradle build flavors.